# How do I add new sibling element using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

My goal it to enter a new `category` node into this XML.

```
<<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<categories xmlns="CategoryList.xsd" lastSavedTime="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5903428Z">
   <category renameOnFirstUse="1" name="Red category" color="0" keyboardShortcut="0" lastTimeUsedNotes="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedJournal="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedContacts="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedTasks="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedCalendar="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedMail="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsed="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" guid="{4f331f68-b735-4797-a0c4-9b02e13d079f}">
      <category renameOnFirstUse="0" name="test" color="10" keyboardShortcut="0" lastTimeUsedNotes="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedJournal="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedContacts="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedTasks="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedCalendar="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedMail="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsed="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" guid="{4452319c-0253-4764-a72f-065e5a4af017}" />
   </category>
   <category renameOnFirstUse="1" name="Orange category" color="1" keyboardShortcut="0" lastTimeUsedNotes="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedJournal="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedContacts="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedTasks="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedCalendar="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedMail="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsed="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" guid="{eb64b97a-d5a2-41ed-a0ed-dc60fe0601e2}" />
   <category renameOnFirstUse="1" name="Yellow category" color="3" keyboardShortcut="0" lastTimeUsedNotes="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedJournal="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedContacts="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedTasks="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedCalendar="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedMail="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsed="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" guid="{0010faba-dd02-44fb-afbe-3fd5ac2d4f6f}" />
   <category renameOnFirstUse="1" name="Green category" color="4" keyboardShortcut="0" lastTimeUsedNotes="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedJournal="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedContacts="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedTasks="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedCalendar="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedMail="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsed="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" guid="{38f5e37c-0fe7-41c4-b265-7b30b9a6fcfa}" />
   <category renameOnFirstUse="1" name="Blue category" color="7" keyboardShortcut="0" lastTimeUsedNotes="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedJournal="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedContacts="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedTasks="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedCalendar="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedMail="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsed="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" guid="{7fb0e73e-4193-4836-b9e9-c2017168418a}" />
   <category renameOnFirstUse="1" name="Purple category" color="8" keyboardShortcut="0" lastTimeUsedNotes="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedJournal="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedContacts="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedTasks="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedCalendar="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsedMail="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" lastTimeUsed="2014-05-02T20:07:40.5279436Z" guid="{0ed51616-504f-4415-936c-a97658aa2458}" />
</categories>
```

But when I try

```
categories = doc.css("category")
categories.after "<test></test>"
```

I get : `nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:59:in 'after': undefined method 'after' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

I know that all the categories are getting read into the `categories` variable because I can print them out. I just haven't been able to add a new category to the XML document.

I also tried `doc.at('category').add_next_sibling("<AnotherNode>13</AnotherNode>")`. That gives the same error: `undefined method 'add_next_sibling' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We'd like to see a small example of the code rather than a commentary of what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

Using Nokogiri 1.6.8 I'm not able to duplicate the problem:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML('<root><node1/></root>')
doc.at('node1').after('<node2/>')
puts doc.to_xml

# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <root>
# >>   <node1/>
# >>   <node2/>
# >> </root>
```

I'd suggest checking your XML. Here's what I get using your XML sample:

```
doc.errors # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: StartTag: invalid element name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document>]
```

Which occurs because of:

```
<<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Reducing the XML to a bare outline shows Nokogiri is being forced to fix up the content to make it parseable:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML('<<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<categories>
   <category>
      <category />
   </category>
</categories>')
doc.errors # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: StartTag: invalid element name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document>]
puts doc.to_xml

# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Rule one: when debugging this stuff reduce the problem to the minimum input and code and see what happens. Fix the XML and you'll probably have better results.

Comment: sigh....  I did not think that was the problem bcz I tried `doc = Nokogiri::XML(data) { |config| config.strict }` which is supposed throw an error if it has any problem reading the XML.  I could also I search and traverse the loaded doc just fine. So, I made the wrong assumption the malformed XML is not the issue.